# Unable to access cross account S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying setup Bucket Policy to allow cross account access.

I have the following setup in my bucket but still got Access Denied error when calling from AWS SDK.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "CrossAccountPutGet",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-task-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:*Object",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The snippet of the Java code is simple, just

```
            String region = s3Clientdefault.getBucketLocation(currentBucket);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your code is running in **Account-A** and the S3 bucket is in **Account-B**.

The **Bucket Policy** you have shown should be applied to the Bucket in **Account-B**.

The code is using an IAM Role from **Account-A**, so let's call it **Role-A**.

In addition to the Bucket Policy on **Bucket-B**, you will also need to **add permissions to Role-A** that grant it access to **Bucket-B**. That is, permissions are required from BOTH SIDES -- **Role-A** needs permission to *use* S3 and **Bucket-B** grants permission for **Role-A** to use the bucket.

The IAM Policy on **Role-A** would be similar to the Bucket Policy, but the `Principal` is not required:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*Object",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks John. I added the policy to Account A role. It seems to pass the GetBucketLocation call, as I am not seeing the stacktrace at that line of code anymore, but it failed in the PutObject call. I even tried s3:* for all operations but it still the same

Comment: I got it now, thanks John. My bucket Resource was set incorrectly